# How to change the background color of a single cell in reporting services 2005

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to change the background color of single cell be based on a string value and wanted to see this expression code.

I was reading a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376/add-alternating-row-color-to-sql-server-reporting-services-report), but this is not the exact same issue I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing along the name of the color you want to use as a string, then just refer to that column in your expression:

Example Query:

```
SELECT 'Green' as BG_Color
```

BackgroundColor Expression:

```
=Fields!BG_Color.Value
```