# Reporting Services custom code not executing

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008

I'm using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376/add-alternating-row-color-to-sql-server-reporting-services-report/83832#83832) in my report, to alternate row colors of grouped rows.

It works correctly on my development server (`SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition`), but not on the live server (`SQL Server 2008 Express`).

Is there a limitation on `Reporting Services` in the `Express edition` that might cause this? Or perhaps security settings that might need to be changed on the live server?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Reporting Services in SQL Server Express with Advanced Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166.aspx) for "key differences" and [Editions and Components of SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144275.aspx) has more info.

Comment: There's nothing in either of those pages that would explain what's happening