# Row colouring in rdlc report

Tags: c#, rdlc

Actually I need to color 2 row one color and next 2 row another color ,alternatively in rdlc report.
For example  1st and 2nd row should be in red color and 3rd and 4th should be in yellow.Again 5th and 6th should be in red and 7th and 8th should be in yellow ...etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is very similar to what you would do if you were coloring every alternate row, you just need a small change to the `Mod` calculation:

```
= IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 4 < 2, "FirstColor", "SecondCOlor")
```

This is untested, but should be enough to get you going.

Check this previous SO post for further examples: [Add alternating row color to SQL Server Reporting services report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376/add-alternating-row-color-to-sql-server-reporting-services-report)