# Hide a row from the details group, but include it in parent group subtotals

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm tinkering with a sales report in which I need to have the ability to hide certain rows from the details, but still include them in group subtotals. If I set a filter on the details group to eliminate these rows based on the appropriate criteria, they're no longer included in the group subtotals. If I adjust the row visibility for the detail row, I can hide them using the same criteria, and the numbers are included in the subtotals, but this messes up the counting of RowNumber(), and the banded rows look like a mess. Is there another clever way of doing this that I'm overlooking?

Comment: What expression/code are you using for alternate row color?

Comment: Just the standard `RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376/add-alternating-row-color-to-sql-server-reporting-services-report).

I prefer [Catch22's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15428/catch22) answer due to simplicity of the expression needed for the BackgroundColor property. It also seems to be more robust when dealing with grouping than the `=IIF(RunningValue...` approach.

### Summary

Add this code:

```
Private bOddRow As Boolean
'*************************************************************************
' -- Display green-bar type color banding in detail rows
' -- Call from BackGroundColor property of all detail row textboxes
' -- Set Toggle True for first item, False for others.
'*************************************************************************
Function AlternateColor(ByVal OddColor As String, _
         ByVal EvenColor As String, ByVal Toggle As Boolean) As String
    If Toggle Then bOddRow = Not bOddRow
    If bOddRow Then
        Return OddColor
    Else
        Return EvenColor
    End If
End Function
```

Then use this expression for the BackgroundColor property value on detail cells:

```
=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", True)
```

Comment: In lieu of anything more declarative, this seems like a decent way to do it. Though I think more elaborate trickery would be necessary for a matrix with row and column groups.