# SSRS : Get Row value

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, row

thus it possible to get the row value in my report and put in textbox?
For example in my Row value, I have
ID
1
2
3
4

I want it to put in textbox with value of 1, 2, 3, 4.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression is;

```
=RowNumber(Nothing)
```

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159225(v=sql.100).aspx)

This ONLY works within tablixes, normally used in conjunction with the BackgroundColor of the cell for reports that use alternating rows;

[Link to StackOverFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376/add-alternating-row-color-to-sql-server-reporting-services-report)

Regards,