# SSRS: each group with a different color?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, business-intelligence, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

How can I format each group in SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS) with a different background color and the items of the group with the same color Scale ? as in the following image :

any Hints or Ideas?

thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to do this.

The way I usually end up doing it is with either a table with your colors joined to your data, a function for your colors, or an expression to choose the color.

If you only have 2 or 3 groups, you best bet may be to use an IIF like:

```
=IIF(FIELDS!GROUP.VALUE = "Group 1", "GRAY", IIF(FIELDS!GROUP.VALUE = "Group 2", "IndianRed", "LightSteelBlue"))
```

Here are good examples of the various methods:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2797/different-ways-to-create-custom-colors-for-charts-in-sql-server-reporting-services/

If you're looking for alternating row colors for the detail, check out this:

[Add alternating row color to SQL Server Reporting services report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376/add-alternating-row-color-to-sql-server-reporting-services-report)

You could incorporate both into your detail:

```
=Code.AlternateColor(IIF(FIELDS!GROUP.VALUE = "Group 1", "Gray"
 IIF(FIELDS!GROUP.VALUE = "Group 2", "IndianRed", "LightSteelBlue")),
 IIF(FIELDS!GROUP.VALUE = "Group 1", "LightGray", IIF(FIELDS!GROUP.VALUE = "Group 2", "MistyRose", "AliceBlue")), True)
```