# Add alternating row color to group on SSRS report

Tags: formatting, ssrs-2012

I am trying to add alternative colours on the column in my report. I have a matrix with a group on the column I want to alternate. I've used the following within the report properties code:

```
Private bOddRow(10) As Boolean 

Function AlternateColor(ByVal OddColor As String, ByVal EvenColor As String, ByVal Toggle As Boolean, ByVal Type AS INTEGER) As String 

  If Toggle Then bOddRow(Type) = Not bOddRow(Type) 

  If bOddRow(Type) Then 
            Return OddColor 
  Else 
            Return EvenColor 
  End If 

End Function
```

And the following within the cells background colour property

```
=code.AlternateColor("White","Silver",0, 1)
```

From the following thread -
[Add alternating row color to SQL Server Reporting services report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376/add-alternating-row-color-to-sql-server-reporting-services-report)

My table is set out as follows
[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk36Y.png)

The [VALUE] field is the cell I'm adding the colour formatting to. For the table example the colours are coming out in a checkerboard effect. However another table I have where the row group and column group are switched ([MATCHING_NAME] and [NAME]) it works fine. I can't figure out why, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just stick with something simple like:
`=iif(RunningValue(Fields!FieldName.Value,CountDistinct,Nothing) Mod 2, "LIGHTBLUE", "SILVER")`

Source: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3490/alternate-row-background-color-in-sql-server-reporting-services-tablix-and-matrix/

It even explains about separate grouping alternating colours which is what you are after.

It also shows you how to do it based on whether it is a table or it is a matrix.

Comment: This doesn't work as I have some empty values - which ideally need to stay that way